# Fiddler 4-iOS 10.2.1 cannot reach internet after configure proxy

Tags: fiddler

I am following this instruction http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForiOS. Everything works until section `Set the iOS Device Proxy`.

Once I set the proxy on my iPhone, I can't connect to the internet from the phone anymore. Not even accessing the echo page, which I could access before turning on the proxy on the phone. I already installed the root cert on my phone, the makecert add-on on Fiddler

Could someone help with ideas to diagnose the issue here? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What might be stopping your iphone from reaching your Fiddler machine on the port specified, usually 8888?

- Have you a firewall on the Fiddler machine? You might need to open
  the port.
- Does your LAN have an automatic redirect to a login page?    Ours
  does, so I have to disable the proxy on the iphone while I    login,
  then reenable it.
- Does your LAN expose the IPs of cable-connected machines to WIFI
  users? Not all do.
- Can you browse a simple web page on your Fiddler machine from your
  iphone, before starting fiddler or doing any proxy configuration?
- You might need to get really serious and install a [ping utility](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-ping-your-network-from-an-iphone) on the iphone.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I restarted Fiddler, tried to re-install the CertMaker add-on again, remove the cert from my iPhone and re-install from the 8888 page again, disconnect my iPhone from Wi-Fi and reconnect. Not necessarily in that order. And somehow it worked. I have not tried again but finger-cross it should just work. I did check my Firewall and yes, the port was opened. And no login re-direct since it's my home network